# Can i return to a view from href tag in laravel without using controller?

Tags: php, view, laravel-5, href

I have a page `home.blade.php`.there is an href tag in this page which redirect to another page `login.blade.php`.

```
<a href="{{URL::to('login')}}">Login</a>.Any simple method to return to that page directly from this href tag?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

You can redirect at any blade template via Route::get, without using a controller.

**In routes web.php**

```
Route::get('/login', function(){
    return view('login'); // Your Blade template name
});
```